# FeedMe - all sites get overwritten by other foreign sites import, even though fields are translatable per group

Tags: craft3, multi-site, plugin-feedme, sites

I have about 16 sites added to my Craft CMS install. They are grouped together by language, so for example, I have 6 sites in English, and 4 sites in Spanish, 2 in German, and then some individual ones.

I have set the Sections to "Propagate entries across all enabled sites?" because when we create a new site, or a new entry, say in Spanish, we would want all the same pages created and connected to other pages in other sites, and would be expecting the pages to be in the language of the group the site was in.

I have a matrix field in which I have set some fields to translate per site group, and others to be not-translatable.

If I import the main US site first, it goes well, then if I import say German next, it seems all sites content is updated to German. but all other sites are in a different group.

I am sure I did not have this issue before when importing.

Editing and saving an entry in German does not then change the US, so its just when importing.

I have previously read when importing Matrix it does not update fields within it, but deletes it and re-creates it. So is it doing this on all sites?

How can one set the main matrix field to be translatable per group so it does not get touched in other groups? The only option is "Manage blocks on a per-site basis" which we would not want, as it needs to be the same **per group**. I assume there should be a field "Manage blocks on a per-**group** basis"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior when importing Matrix blocks, currently. See my [comment](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/463#issuecomment-504988387) on [craftcms/feed-me#463](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/463) for a full explanation and possible workaround.

Comment: I can undertstand it being tricky to manage content within matrix blocks, so deleting and recreating is fine, but it should be within a group only, not for all sites/groups. My german in the German group is overwriting the others like English. We cannot “Manage blocks on a per-site basis” as this means all our common languages (e.g. lots of countries speak English and Spanish) would need managing on a per site basis, rather than one site per group. But does the 3.2 update with propagating content per group address this?